# Unix > overwrite command?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I'm doing a shell command (such as `sh run.sh > log.txt`). How do you overwrite the file each time (so each time I run it `log.txt` doesn't get appended)

I'm doing this in a python script and I'm checking the log file each time for a specific number (and I don't want the numbers to get added onto the `log.txt`, just replaced)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>` operator DOES overwrite the file by first truncating it to be empty and then writing. The `>>` operator would append. Perhaps you are actually using that?

Comment: ya your right.... apparently I was using the wrong one in the script. My bad

Comment: And if you want your existing files to be protected against using `>` by mistake instead of `>>`, you can put `set -o noclobber` in your `.bashrc`

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: True, but that's a little bit dangerous in the same way that aliasing rm to some kind of trash command is: it sets you up with a safety net that creates bad habits that get you burned when the net is gone.

Comment: I understand your point, but cannot entirely agree. Yes, *not paying attention* to what you type is a bad habit. But mistakes happen to everyone - it is human. So maybe the best way would be to first learn things the hard way (no safety nets) and then open some nets, where the results of mistakes can be dramatic. But this is a matter of individual philosophy, of course.